# など after verb phrase

Tags: grammar, reading-comprehension, particle-など

The first sentence below is just for context.The second is where my problems lie.

> 日産は、工場から日本の店に車を出すのをしばらく止めると発表しました。
>   Nissan announced that, for a while, it will stop sending cars, from the factories *where the safety inspectors are unqualified*, to Japanese shops.
>   そして、車の検査をする場所には資格がある人以外**入る**ことができないようにする**など**、同じ問題が起こらないようにする方法を考えます。
>   And, they will make sure that no one who isn't qualified can enter the places where the cars are inspected など they are thinking of ways to make sure that the same problem won't happen.

I have three problems with my translation of the second sentence. Point 1 is my main problem but I'm uncomfortable about the other two points.

1. I Have no idea how など is supposed to link these two parts. Is this a bit like たり?
2. 入る has no subject. Am I right to assume it is just an implied 'no one', or have I mis-parsed the clause?
3. The final clause feels incomplete. I would expect words like 'again' or 'in the future'.

Comment: Okay, you know the context. I was looking for the equivalent sentence “where the safety inspectors are unqualified” coming from the sentence in Japanese.

Comment: @kimiTanaka That's why I put it in italic font. It's not in the sentence, but without it it sounds weird. Full text here: http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011183511000/k10011183511000.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「そして、車{くるま}の検査{けんさ}をする場所{ばしょ}には資格{しかく}がある人以外{ひといがい}**入る**ことができないようにする**など**、同{おな}じ問題{もんだい}が起{お}こらないようにする方法{ほうほう}を考{かんが}えます。」
>
> 1. I Have no idea how など is supposed to link these two parts.

「など」 is used to give an example of the 「同じ問題が起こらないようにする方法」.

To translate that sentence, therefore, you would need to ***drastically*** change the word order into something like:

"**To make sure that the same problem won't happen, Nissan will consider measures, such as allowing no one who isn't qualified to enter the places where the cars are inspected**."

> Is this a bit like たり?

Only in the sense that both 「など」 and 「たり」 can be used to exemplify things, yes.  「たり」, however, is far more informal than many J-learners seem to think.  In addition, the two words follow two different verb forms -- 「～～**する**など」 and 「～～**し**たり」.  Thus, the two words are ***not*** interchangeable.

> 2. 入る has no subject. Am I right to assume it is just an implied 'no one', or have I mis-parsed the clause?

It has a ***clear*** subject in 「資格がある人以外」= "those who are not qualified".  So, your TL is fine there.

> 3. The final clause feels incomplete. I would expect words like 'again' or 'in the future'.

It is complete for the Japanese-speaking brain.  The use of 「同じ」 suggests that it happened once.  "Again" or "in the future" is implied here.